# How to force Rails 4 app into production mode in Nginx and Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I am running a Rails 4 app on a VPS with Ubuntu, NginX and Unicorn.

When I SSL into my server and update the app via git or run rake tasks on the database, my app always switches to `development` mode and I can't get it into `production` mode.

Typing `RAILS_ENV=production` seems to have no effect at all.

When I do

```
$ rails console
$ Rails.env
```

I get

> --> development

all the time.

What must I do to force NginX into `production` mode?

Actually, I don't want Nginx to **ever** run in `development` mode.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is your ROR app getting started?  Passenger?  Unicorn?  `ENV` vars work, but the answer depends on how you're invoking Rails.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is probably running in production mode by default. What you're doing is engaging a shell, something using a different environment.

Normally on a production server you'd put this into your profile script:

```
# Add to ~/.bash_profile
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

That way when you power up `rails c` you will get the correct environment.

As a note, the only way this shell is engaging in the first place is that you have a `development` setting in your `config/database.yml`. That shouldn't be there, as the configuration for your production server should be production-only.

Answer (score 2):

nginx doesn't run in development or production mode - your app does, via your unicorn configuration and/or the RAILS_ENV environment variable when you launch your unicorn instances.

You should be launching your unicorn instances with the `RAILS_ENV` variable prefixed to the command, eg:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

`rails console` launches a completely different instance which may be in an different environment - it is unrelated to your unicorn instances. If you want to launch a production console instance, then either invoke `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` or `rails console production`. Note that this has no bearing on the environment that your application runs in.

Comment: You don't need the environment variable per se, but you do need to specify the Rails/Rack environment. Unicorn, like most recent Rack-compliant servers, accepts an environment argument (`-E` or `--env`).

Comment: True, but using environment variables will consistently work no matter how you launch the app.